# How to convert PCollection<List<String>> to PCollection<String> in dataflow/beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a use case in which I need to output multiple `T` from a DoFn. So `DoFn` function is returning a `PCollection<List<T>>`. I want to convert it to `PCollection<T>` so that later in pipeline I can just filter like:

```
PCollection<T> filteredT = filterationResult.apply(Filter.byPredicate(p -> p.equals(T) == T));
```

Currently the best method I can think of is, instead returning `List<T>` from the `ParDo` function I return `KV<String,List<T>>` with same key for every item. Then in pipeline I can do below to combine result:

```
filterationResult.apply("Group", GroupByKey.<String, List<T>>create())
```

Or can I call `c.output(T)` from DoFn (where `c` is the `ProcessContext` object passed in) multiple times?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call `c.output(T)` from a `DoFn` multiple times.

There is also a library transform [`Flatten.iterables()`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Flatten.html#iterables--) but you don't need it in this case.